# Use batch command to search text file and remove strings

Tags: android, batch-file

I am writing a batch script for a simple android app that will pull the bootclasspath and save to a text file with:

```
adb shell echo $BOOTCLASSPATH > tmp.txt
```

This outputs the following to the text file

```
/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/framework2.jar:/system/framework/telephony-common.jar:/system/framework/mms-common.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/sec_edm.jar:/system/framework/seccamera.jar:/system/framework/scrollpause.jar:/system/framework/stayrotation.jar:/system/framework/smartfaceservice.jar:/system/framework/abt-persistence.jar:/system/framework/secocsp.jar:/system/framework/sc.jar
```

This issue is I do not need the preceding string "/system/framework" to be saved into the text.  That's just the path to the file and I don't need it.

So how can i use a batch command to search that file and remove all references of "/system/framework/" and save to a new file?

I tried this example to no avail....

```
findstr /V "/system/framework" tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
```

I also used this to remove just the first reference of the string by deleting the first 18 characters...which did work....but obviously did not remove the other references....

```
@echo off
Set "InputFile=tmp.txt"
Set "OutputFile=tmp2.txt"
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion > "%OutputFile%"
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims= " %%a in ("%InputFile%") do (
set s=%%a
>> "%OutputFile%" echo.!s:~18!
)
```

How can I delete every instance of "/system/framework/" in my text file using a batch command?

Or even better, how can i extract the bootclasspath without that extra info?

Thanks,
Jimmie

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (tmp.txt) DO SET "BOOTCLASSPATH=%%a"
SET "BOOTCLASSPATH=%BOOTCLASSPATH:/system/framework/=%"
ECHO %BOOTCLASSPATH%
```

---

```
core.jar:core-junit.jar:bouncycastle.jar:ext.jar:framework.jar:framework2.jar:telephony-common.jar:mms-common.jar:android.policy.jar:services.jar:apache-xml.jar:sec_edm.jar:seccamera.jar:scrollpause.jar:stayrotation.jar:smartfaceservice.jar:abt-persistence.jar:secocsp.jar:sc.jar
```